# Zend Framework 2 Db2

Tags: db2, zend-db, zend-framework2

I have recently started development on a new application with Zend Framework 2 rc7 but I have been unable to find any reference to a DB2 Adapter.

does anyone know if there are plans to develop one?

So far I have written my own custom DB2 adapter extending many of the Zend Db classes but this is not as full featured as I would like it to be.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently it will be some time before ZF works with DB2. It should have worked through PDO_ODBC but I see from this issue that it will not be fixed: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-905

Comment: If you have a partial implementation then you could send the code to the zend framework repository, by this way other developers can improve your code and send more and better contributions.

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps to use the adapter Pdo_Mssql with the option pdoType = dblib (http://fr2.php.net/pdo-dblib)

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.adapter-notes.pdo-mssql